# Should I use a vector of tuple or vector of array?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, std

I'm trying to have a vector of points. How should I construct my vector?

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3> > listA;
```

vs

```
std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double> > listB;
```

Is there any performance advantage if I choose one vs the other?

Comment: `array` compiles faster and is standard layout. `tuple` is a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any features of `std::tuple` here, so go with the most standard tool that works. And that is `std::array`.

(Or some `using ... = std::array;` or `struct {std::array};` with a nice name.)

Concerning performance, you would have to measure. But I am pretty sure that `std::array` is at least as fast as `std::tuple`, but most likely equally fast as both do all their work at compile time.